# Semantic exception error for Hive UDF. I am trying to test by reversing a string

Tags: java, class, oop, hadoop, hive

This is my Hive UDF. My classes and methods seem fine to me and the first method works too but the second method does not when I give the Hive command `select to_upper('abc','def');`

```
package com.hive.udf;

import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MyUpperUDF extends UDF {
    public MyUpperUDF(){
        System.out.println("Inside the constructor");
    }
    public String evaluate(String data){
        System.out.println("Inside the evaluate method");
        return data.toUpperCase();
    }
    public String evaluate(Text data1,String data2){
        System.out.println("Inside evaluate - concatenate & reverse method");
        String temp = data1.toString()+data2;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(temp);
        return sb.reverse().toString();
    }

}
```

I am getting the following error:
[image: Error]
Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Error clearly says that, there is no evaluate function with (String, String) parameters. Your program have 2 evaluate functions - one with String and other with Text and String. Try changing the second to String, String.